# Where can I find a global life expectancy table?

Tags: population-dynamics, population-biology, lifespan

I've found good information on specific countries and demographics, but I can't seem to find global numbers.  I know that the world life expectancy is around 71.0, but I'm trying to get a percentile breakdown in the form of something like an actuarial life table.

Answer (score 2):

Not surprisingly, the WHO has a lot of data, I think especially interesting for you is this interactive figure, which you can find [here](http://gamapserver.who.int/gho/interactive_charts/mbd/life_expectancy/atlas.html):

[image]

Other data on this topic can be found on the WHO website [here](http://www.who.int/gho/mortality_burden_disease/life_tables/en/), in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy) or from the [Worldbank](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.DYN.LE00.IN).